# vimrc file comments - double-quotes vs two double-quotes

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm going through a .vimrc file and there everything is written like this : -

```
" Better copy & paste
" When you want to paste large blocks of code into vim, press F2 before you
" paste. At the bottom you should see ``-- INSERT (paste) --``.

"" set pastetoggle=<F2>
"" set clipboard=unnamed


" Mouse and backspace
"" set mouse=a  " on OSX press ALT and click
"" set bs=2     " make backspace behave like normal again


" Rebind <Leader> key
" I like to have it here becuase it is easier to reach than the default and
" it is next to ``m`` and ``n`` which I use for navigating between tabs.
"" let mapleader = ","


" Bind nohl
" Removes highlight of your last search
" ``<C>`` stands for ``CTRL`` and therefore ``<C-n>`` stands for ``CTRL+n``
"" noremap <C-n> :nohl<CR>
"" vnoremap <C-n> :nohl<CR>
"" inoremap <C-n> :nohl<CR>


" Quicksave command
"" noremap <C-Z> :update<CR>
"" vnoremap <C-Z> <C-C>:update<CR>
"" inoremap <C-Z> <C-O>:update<CR>
```

Can someone tell me what is difference between those lines written after `" ....`
and the lines written after `"".....` ?

Comment: I have never seen this before. I thought one just wrote the comments, e.g. what I have in my vimrc is a line that says `:syntax on` and thats it...is that wrong?

Answer (score 34):

This is the main difference:

```
" Comments to describe what the line of code below does
"" Actual working code for the .vimrc file but still commented.
```

So that when you see double "double quotes" it's commented code, you can uncomment it by removing the double "double quotes", the single "double quotes" mean "I'm just a comment" and are not to be "uncommented", makes sense?. Hope this helps. Do not hesitate to ask if another doubt comes up!

**UPDATE 0**: In the `.vimrc` file, line comments are made by adding a double quote `"` to the left of the text, this means that everything to the right of the `"` is a comment; multiline comments can't be made in the `.vimrc` file except adding a `"` to the beginning of each line, thus resulting in multiple single-line comment unlike `C` or `PHP` where you can use these opening-multiline-comment `/*` and closing-multiline-comment `*/` . I don't know if it's still out there but there was a plugin called "The NERD plugin" or "The NERD Commenter" in `vim`. Hope this helps!

**UPDATE 1**: With regards to the double "double quotes" and single "double quotes", for example the first lines in your `.vimrc` file:

> **"** Better copy & paste
> **"** When you want to paste large blocks of code into vim, press F2 before you
> **"** paste. At the bottom you should see `-- INSERT (paste) --`.
>
> **"***"* set pastetoggle=
> **"***"* set clipboard=unnamed

Please note at the start of each line there's a **bolded double quote** like this **"** this means that every single text character in that line starting immediately to the right of it is a comment.

Now, notice the last two lines where there are double "double quotes" at the beginning of those lines. The first character in the line is a **bolded double quote** like this **"** and the second character in the line is an *Italic double quote* like this *"*. Again, as explained above, this means that every single text character in that line starting immediately to the right of it is a comment. Now the second "double quote" is part of the comment, you could even add 3 or more double quotes, because when a line has the double quote character *everything to the right will be interpreted as a comment*. This is just for the programmers or users to detect faster where is the working code and where are the plain comments, a visual reference. Hope this helps. Again, do not hesitate to ask if there's any doubt, Cheers!

Comment: Hello there! Then I suggest that you be a little bit more specific or ask another question. What is it specifically that you'd like to know?

Comment: you told me the difference between the " and "" with reference of the above .vimrc file . Try to tell the actual difference between them and the different ways to comments the .vimrc file.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay There is only one way to comment in vim, and there is no syntactic difference between `"` and `""` for comments.

Comment: I have never seen this before. I thought one just wrote the comments, e.g. what I have in my vimrc is a line that says `:syntax on` and thats it...is that wrong?

Comment: I had no idea this was some sort of convention. And if it isn't, it should be. It's a fine idea. Thank you. Next time I open my `.vimrc` I'm adding an extra quote mark to the commented-out commands.